# How to check for iOS5 using web technologies?

Tags: ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile app using jQuery Mobile and I would like to check if I'm on iOS5, cause it has some great features, like [true fixed toolbars](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html), etc. I'm looking for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with a bit of string manipulation of the user-agent.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var detail = ua.split('(')[1];
var device = detail.split(';')[0];
if (device == 'iPhone' || device == 'iPod' || device == 'iPad') {
    var ios = detail.split(' ')[5].split('_')[0];
    if (ios == '5') {
        alert('ios 5');
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work for Safari but may not work if the web page is executing in a third-party app and the developer has changed the User Agent value using one of the techniques that are out there to do this.

Comment: Sorry I presumed the OP wanted a solution for mobile safari

Comment: Does this work if I create an app with PhoneGap? As I understand, PhoneGap will create a UIWebView control. Will this then work? If not, is there a solution for this?

Comment: It should do - let me know if it doesn't and I will revise my answer